# opencv python merge different channel images into one

Tags: python, image, opencv, numpy

I have few satellite images each of them represents one channel of main satellite image,  these are 11 images in total, each are labled with different channel, all images are in .tiff format with grayscale colorspace, now i simply want's to merge these images into one, to represent all channels into one image, so is this possible, remeber here, I don't want to concat images , which can be done using this:

```
vis = np.concatenate((img1, img2), axis=1)
```

I want to merge all of them into one single image , without distorting the data contained within, few channel images are attached below.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you upload without white borders?

Comment: The maximum channels a typical RGB image can have is 3 only, how do you want to merge 11 channels into single image? Do you mean to add them ?

Comment: They are not RGB images they are grayscale with 3 tupple values for each pixel I want to create one single image by merging all 11 images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `OpenCV 3.x` stored image as `numpy` array, we can simply average each image and add them together, provided that the height and width of the images are exactly the same.

```
img_1 = cv2.imread('./imagesStackoverflow/sat_1_331-442.png')
img_2 = cv2.imread('./imagesStackoverflow/sat_2_331-442.png')
img_3 = cv2.imread('./imagesStackoverflow/sat_3_331-442.png')
img_4 = cv2.imread('./imagesStackoverflow/sat_4_331-442.png')

no_img = 4
img = img_1/no_img + img_2/no_img + img_3/no_img + img_4/no_img
```

To get a quick result, I manually edited the size of the four images to `442(h) x 331(w)` pixels.

[image]
Below is the merged image, with 3 channels.

[image]

To merge 11 images, you may just extend the code as:

```
img = img_1/no_img + img_2/no_img + img_3/no_img + ... + img_11/no_img
```

Comment: This approach works fine, as excpected, also from opencv 2.2.x onwards all images are natively used as numpy array. This also works on OpenCV 2.2.x as well.

Answer (score 9):

First, you need to `carefully` consider the `number of channels` that you have so that you can create a useful image. In the example below I assume that you have three channels (Red, Green, and Blue) which could be combined into an RGB image.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

"""Read each channel into a numpy array. 
Of course your data set may not be images yet.
So just load them into three different numpy arrays as neccessary"""
a = cv2.imread('chanel_1.jpg', 0)
b = cv2.imread('chanel_2.jpg', 0)
c = cv2.imread('chanel_3.jpg', 0)

"""Create a blank image that has three channels 
and the same number of pixels as your original input"""
needed_multi_channel_img = np.zeros((a.shape[0], a.shape[1], 3))

"""Add the channels to the needed image one by one"""
needed_multi_channel_img [:,:,0] = a
needed_multi_channel_img [:,:,1] = b
needed_multi_channel_img [:,:,2] = c

"""Save the needed multi channel image"""
cv2.imwrite('needed_multi_channel_img.png',needed_multi_channel_img)
```

Comment: Even simpler : img=cv2.merge((b,g,r))

Answer (score 3):

I've been trying this for 2 days straight and one thing that I failed to understand was that the merge function of opencv takes a tuple, not 3 different arguments.

```
image = cv2.imread(image_file, 1)
R, G, B = cv2.split(image)
output_image = cv2.merge ( (R, G, B) )
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by merge ? They are all grayscale images, so they are basically the same channel in grayscale color space. Some information are doomed to be lost when you try to [blend](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html) or [add](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageChops.html) the images. Try the above two methods using functions in OpenCV or Pillow.

```
mul1 = ImageChops.add(img1, img2, scale=2)
mul2 = ImageChops.add(img3, img4, scale = 2)
mul3 = ImageChops.add(mul1, mul2, scale = 2)

mul3.show()
```

[image: using Add]

```
R1 = img1.convert('RGBA').resize([456,512])
R2 = img2.convert('RGBA').resize([456,512])
R3 = img3.convert('RGBA')
R4 = img4.convert('RGBA')

S1 = ImageChops.blend(R1,R2,0.5)
S2 = ImageChops.blend(R3,R4,0.5)
S3 = ImageChops.blend(S1,S2,0.5)
S3.show()
```

[image: Using Blend]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Python code for the same. It takes in images of any channel, but the width and height has to be maintained as is the case with hcontat, vcontat, hstack, vstack.

1. scale: scales the final image by a given number
2. imgArray: is the array of all the images you want to concatenate, no matter the channels in each of the images

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
def stackImages(scale,imgArray):
    rows = len(imgArray)
    cols = len(imgArray[0])
    rowsAvailable = isinstance(imgArray[0],list)
    width = imgArray[0][0].shape[1]
    height = imgArray[0][0].shape[0]
    if rowsAvailable:
        for x in range(0,rows):
            for y in range(0, cols):
                if imgArray[x][y].shape[:2] == imgArray[x][y].shape[:2]:
                    imgArray[x][y] = cv2.resize(imgArray[x][y],(0,0),None,scale,scale)
                else:
                    imgArray[x][y] = cv2.resize(imgArray[x][y], (imgArray[0][0].shape[0]), None, scale, scale)
                if len(imgArray[x][y].shape) == 2: imgArray[x][y] =cv2.cvtColor(imgArray[x][y],cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        imageBlank = np.zeros((height,width,3), np.uint8)
        hor = [imageBlank]*rows
        hor_con = [imageBlank]*rows
        for x in range(0, rows):
            hor[x] = np.hstack(imgArray[x])
        ver = np.vstack(hor)
    else:
        for x in range(0, rows):
            if imgArray[x].shape[:2] == imgArray[0].shape[:2]:
                imgArray[x] = cv2.resize(imgArray[x],(0,0),None,scale,scale)
            else:
                imgArray[x] = cv2.resize(imgArray[x],(imgArray[0].shape[0],imgArray[0].shape[1]),None,scale,scale)
            if len(imgArray[x].shape) == 2: imgArray[x] =cv2.cvtColor(imgArray[x],cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        hor = np.hstack(imgArray)
        ver = hor
    return ver
```

The function *stackedImages(scale, imageArray)* belonged to the package created by the person who was giving tutorials on trackbars and live object detection. Check here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fchzk1lDt7Q&t=25s

Comment: this is an inexplicable mess of code that doesn't once mention channels or `cv2.split` and `cv2.merge`

Comment: Care to go through what I have written above and below the code?